# ¿como obtener un valor string aleatorio entre dos variables, usando Javascript y PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, random

estaba buscando la manera de programar una página en la cual en una parte tengo dos opciones a elegir que son dos `input type="text"`, lo que buscaba es que de esas dos opciones con un boton `type="submit"` pasara a una página PHP uno de los valores de estos dos `input` de manera aleatoria.
Este sería el código HTML:

```
<div id="divopciones">
    <div id="div1">                      
        <form name="form1" id="form1id" action="index.php" method="POST">
            1era opcion: <input type="text" name="1erdiv1op" id="form1op1"><br><br>
            2da opcion: &nbsp;<input type="text" name="1erdiv2op" id="form1valor2">
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar" onclick="enviar()">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Este es el codigo HTML en la página "Index.php"

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <br/>
    <label for="inputName">
        <h1 style="color:white;">
            <u>Opcion elegida:</u>
        </h1> 
    </label>
    <br/>
    <div>
        <script>
            <?php
                if(isset($_POST["form1id"])){
                    if($_POST["form1id"])
                        echo "He recibido en el archivo.php: ".$_POST["form1id"];
                    else
                        echo "He recibido un campo vacio";
                }
            ?>
        </script>
    </div>
```

y este es el código JavaScript que me lanza error:

```
//div1
var min = 0;
var max = 1;
function getRandomArbitraryDIV1(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
//funcion que envia variable JS a PHP
function enviar(){       
    var form1valor1 = window.document.divopciones.div1.form1id.form1op1.value;
    var form1valor2 = window.document.divopciones.div1.form1id.form1op2.value;
    var array1 = array(form1valor1, form1valor2); 
    var ValorFinal1 = array1.getRandomArbitraryDIV1();
    // Enviamos la variable de javascript a index.php
    $.post("index.php",{"form1id":ValorFinal1},function(respuesta){
        alert(respuesta);
    });
```

Comment: Y por qué no envías los dos parámetros a PHP y luego eliges uno de ellos?

Comment: De igual manera sale error, creo que hay un error en el código Javascript (dentro de la función) pero no logro saber cual es. Muchas gracias por responder

Comment: Yo me refiero a que no hagas esa lógica en el JavaScript. Haz un formulario simple que envíe los dos parámetros siempre. Luego en el ojo eliges uno al azar.

Comment: Me gusta tambien esa idea pero, de todas formas existe un error en mi código que no me permite pasar los valores del input al archivo index.php, y esa seria mi duda principal.

Comment: En el PHP tienes el problema que compruebas form1id, pero ese es el id del campo, no el nombre. Debes comprobar el nombre del campo, `_POST["1erdiv1op"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varios errores en tu código:

1. En Javascript no puedes crear un array con `array(...valores...)`, puedes usar `[...valores...]` o `new Array (...valores...)`
2. La función que debe devolver el valor aleatorio entre los valores dados está mal. No necesitas complicarte con `min` y `max`. Basta con pasarle en parámetro el array y con el código que hay ahora te devolverá un valor aleatorio.
3. No puedes hacer la llamada como `valor=array.laFuncion`. Sino `valor=laFuncion(array)`

He aquí un código que funciona. He puesto valores a mano para simplificar, sólo tienes que adaptarlo a tu contexto:

```js
function getRandomArbitraryDIV1(array) {
  return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
}

var form1valor1 = 3;
var form1valor2 = 7;
var array1 = [form1valor1, form1valor2];
//Puedes usar también new Array(form1valor1, form1valor2);
var ValorFinal1 = getRandomArbitraryDIV1(array1);
console.log(ValorFinal1);
```

### Código en tu contexto

Este sería el código integrado en tu contexto. He cambiado algunas cosas, recurriendo a mejores prácticas:

1. En vez de llamar la función *in line*  desde el HTML, implementamos una escucha del click del input enviar usando su id. **OBSERVA que ahora ese elemento debes ponerlo así: `<input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="btnEnviar">`**
2. Hacemos un casteo de los valores y los seteamos a `0` cuando sean no numéricos
3. A la parte del `$post` le ponemos su parámetro `done`

Así debería funcionar. Si no funciona, entonces debes revisar tu código en el servidor.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#btnEnviar").click(function(e) {
    /*Impide que se recargue la página al enviar*/
    e.preventDefault();
    /*Si no es número lo convierte a 0*/
    var form1valor1 = $("#form1op1").val();
    var form1valor2 = $("#form1valor2").val();
    var array1 = [form1valor1, form1valor2];
    //Puedes usar también new Array(form1valor1, form1valor2);
    var ValorFinal1 = getRandomArbitraryDIV1(array1);
    $.post("index.php", {
        form1id: ValorFinal1
      })
      .done(function(respuesta) {
        alert("Datos del servidor: " + respuesta);
      });
    console.log(ValorFinal1);
  });

  function getRandomArbitraryDIV1(array) {
    return array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divopciones">
  <div id="div1">
    <form name="form1" id="form1id" action="index.php" method="POST">
      1era opcion: <input type="text" name="1erdiv1op" id="form1op1"><br><br> 2da opcion: &nbsp;<input type="text" name="1erdiv2op" id="form1valor2">
      <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="btnEnviar">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, esa función si funciona, pero mi verdadero problema es que me sale un error cuando intento pasar los valores de los Input del HTML a las variables de JS, y otro error es el de pasar a PHP la variable ValorFinal1.

Comment: @kuper ahora te lo pongo en contexto para que pruebes.

Comment: Muchas gracias! espero con ansias el resultado. :)

Comment: @kuper revisa la respuesta editada. Al final te he puesto el código en el contexto con algunos cambios. Observa bien de hacer los cambios una vez hayas entendido el por qué. Si no funciona debes revisar en el servidor si estás dirigiendo la petición al archivo PHP indicado y cómo se manejan las cosas allí.

Comment: He hecho los cambios en el código pero en el momento de mostrar el alert, aparece asi:
"Datos del servidor: <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
            <title>Undecided</title>soyphp
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/CSS.css">      
        <!--JQUERY CON CDN DE MICROSOFT-->
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
..."

Comment: @kuper es que el archivo al que mandas la petición (en este caso `index.php`)  no debería tener código que salga por pantalla. Ese archivo debe ser un archivo que sirva solamente como pasarela para llevar y traer datos (un archivo PHP puro sin etiquetas HTML ni nada). Por eso te muestra todo su contenido, claro.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias ahí me funcionó, aunque me gustaría saber si podes, como hacer que el valor que se pase no sea solo numérico, es decir que permita elegir de manera aleatoria entre dos elementos String.  Desde ya muchas gracias por la ayuda :))

Comment: @kuper disculpa se me cruzaron los cables y creí que los valores tenían que ser numéricos. He quitado esa restricción en el código, revisa ahora. Sería quitar lo del `parseInt(...) || 0;` dejando solamente la captura de los valores tal cual.

Comment: Listo, muchisimas gracias funciona a la perfección. :)